# change preview in cloud 9 from https to http

Tags: cloud9-ide

I am playing around the cloud9 IDE, the preview is using https, but I have some CDN resource embedded in the page which use http, this is a conflict so that my page does not work. But seems that cloud9 preview only support https. Can I change it to http?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "pop-out" button on the preview pane the page will open in a new browser window. There you can easily change the protocol from `https` to `http`.

However it would be preferable to load the data over https if your CDN support that.

Comment: You suggestion doesn't work. Changing https to http just redirects back to https (301 Moved Permanently)